# Lists class in java 8

Tags: java-8

Via twitter, I discovered [that blog post](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/08/optional-broken/) .
Since I am currently exploring Java 8, I tried running the examples in it.
One thing is that I can not find the class `Lists` (which implements a `map`) like in the examples:

```
Function<String, String> identity = (s -> s); // return the argument

List<String> ls = Arrays.asList("Alice", "Bob", "Christine");
List<String> l2 = Lists.map(ls, identity); // [Alice, Bob, Christine] <- the same thing!
```

Anyone know where I can find it in order to make the example run ?

Thank you

Comment: It's not in java.util?

Comment: I didnt find it in it

Comment: Sorry was thinking of ArrayList.  It's java.awt - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/List.html

Comment: @JohnHalbert I don't think it's that either - Googling yields no classes named `Lists` in the `java.*` package.

Comment: Hmmm... not sure.  That's a link to Java 8 API doc.  It says java.awt.  Take a look there, I think they're the definitive source.

Comment: @JohnHalbert And there seems to be neither a `Lists` class nor a function `static List<R> map(List<T> list, Function<T, R> mapper)` anywhere.

Comment: Also, are we talking about the class or the interface?  Because if you're looking for the List interface, you'll have to implement it in a class of your own.  What are you trying to do?  Is it possible that ArrayList would work for you?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for, but it's not going to work the way you're expecting - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html
With the way you've passed a generic here, it looks like you're trying to use the List interface.  But there is a class List in java.awt that can be used with the asList() method which doesn't accept generics.  Just Depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JohnHalbert There's no reference in the `List` class to any kind of higher-order function such as `map`. OP's blog post seems to imply that there is a `Lists` class with the `static map` function somewhere in the `java.util` package, which doesn't seem to be the case. It could be replicated with the `Stream` API through `map` and `collect` but the OP is asking if there is a default implementation already.

Comment: Actually I think the confusion here is that the blog post referenced was used as an example.  There is no Lists (pluralized here) class at all.  The post was simply saying "if everything was the way it should be, the structure should be unchanged."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no such method in JDK as well as in popular libraries. However you may write it by yourself:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Lists {
    public static <T, R> List<R> map(List<T> input, 
                   Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
        return input.stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found that in google, author should provide the link if that's the class he used in the example...

https://gist.github.com/softprops/406370